# Сайт периодически отправляет 500 ошибку

Tags: python, парсер, api

Мне нужно парсить последние транзакции кошельков Ton-коинов. Для этого я использую их API: https://toncenter.com/api/v2/#/, но периодически мне в логи прилетает ошибка 500.

Вот функция по получению транзакции:

```
def get(self):
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': self.user_agent
    }
    params = {
        'address': self.address,
        'limit': '1',
        'to_lt': '0',
        'archival': 'false',
    }
    response = requests.get('https://toncenter.com/api/v2/getTransactions', params=params, headers=headers,
                            proxies=self.proxy)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response
    else:
        self.l.log_info(f'{self.alias} has got response code: {response.status_code}')
        return
```

Мне нужно парсить 6 кошельков, для парсинга каждого выделен прокси и User-Agent. Задержка между запросами 3 секунды.

Ума не приложу, что еще можно сделать. Прошу, помогите, заранее спасибо!

Comment: HTTP ошибка 500 - это серверная ошибка и никак не связана с клиентом и его запросом.

Comment: [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

Comment: Да, это я знаю, но эту ошибку могут вызывать и неправильные параметры/заголовки, а я не знаю, какие

Comment: Так разве у сервиса который вы используете нет API? Поищите и посмотрите, может вы найдёте за что зацепиться.

Comment: Я использую API, когда мне приходили ошибки 429, там было написано, что не больше 1 запроса в секунду, что я и сделал

Answer (score -1):

[500](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#5xx:%7E:text=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E.-,500%20Internal%20Server%20Error,-%5B23%5D%C2%A0%E2%80%94%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F) - когда сервер не смог нормально отработать. Говорит только о неправильной работе сервера, а не о неправильном запросе.

[406](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#5xx:%7E:text=%D0%B2%20HTTP/1.1.-,406,-Not%20Acceptable%C2%A0%E2%80%94%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) - более вероятный ответ при неправильном запросе.

[400](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#5xx:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F.-,400,-Bad%20Request%C2%A0%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) - правильный ответ от сервера, если ошибка в запросе клиента.

Вероятнее всего API данного сайта не стабилен и/или незакончен. Я рекомендую обратиться с данным вопросом в тех. поддержку, а не на форумы. Ибо ошибка говорит о проблеме на их стороне.

Comment: 500 может возникнуть и в следствии неправильного запроса, в зависимости от того - насколько качественно написан валидатор входных параметров

Comment: @Exord если 500 возникает из-за ошибки запроса - это тоже проблема некачественно сделанного сервера. По стандарту он должен вернуть 400.

Comment: По стандарту он должен вернуть 422 если это ошибка валидации)

Comment: Но если это ошибка параметров запроса - 400.

Comment: не обязательно, 400 довольно общий код ошибки клиентского запроса, не указывающий на что либо конкретно, кроме неправильно составленного запроса. Помимо параметров, могут быть кривые хедеры, поля в body, структура принимаемого значения и тд. Его целесообразно использовать только, если только с 400 присылается портянка проблемы от сервера. В других случаях лучше указывать более конкретный код

Comment: Но не 500. Любой 4XX на выбор. Так что ваша придирка не актуальна.

Comment: ещё раз) 500 может возникнуть и в следствии неправильного запроса. В случае если нет валидатора. - 500 говорит только о том что сервак захлебнулся. А клиент виноват, или сервер - тут нет понимания

Comment: 500 не должен возникнуть в результате некорректного запроса, если сервер сделан правильно. Мы априори рассматриваем идеальные условия.

Comment: Ну тогда извините за придирку "идеальные условия" это не про сервисы которые ранятся на тысячах серверах :) На практике и не такие банальные проблемы бывают.

Comment: Данный ответ лишь перенаправляет вопрос на верный канал (тех. поддержку) и объясняет, что проблема не в запросе. Он не учитывает внешние проблемы, потому что в самом вопросе не указано, что сервер может быть нестабильным.